# How to load Maple package ??

Tags: math-software, maple

I have downloaded second version of [DGApplications](http://digitalcommons.usu.edu/dg_downloads/1/) to work with abstract Lie algebra. The file is actually .mla file and it is executale(as when we open it, a prompt ask, "do you want to execute this file"), but when I press ok for execution, a file open with command like as

"march('open',"C:\Users\Manjit\Downloads\DGApplications.mla");",

what should I do after this, is it a some sort installation procedure. I keep all my Maple file in E drive with following path:

E:\Maple work\General Maple Workout

The help on this issue is also provided on the site as follow but I could go beyond libname:

(1) Create or identify a directory (folder) where you will keep the mla file(s) and the help file. Copy the mla and help files there.

(2) Open Maple, at the prompt type libname. This will display where maple currently looks for packages. You need to modify libname to include the path to the directory used in (1). This can be done by assigning libname := newpath, libname;.

(3) If you are installing the DifferentialGeometry package: Execute with(DifferentialGeometry) to load the package. At the prompt execute DGbuild; and verify that the build number matches the build displayed on this website. This step can be ignored if you are installing DGApplications.

(4) Step (2) can be automatically executed at the start of every Maple session by adding the libname assignment to your maple init file. In Maple Help, see worksheet,reference,initialization. Or go to the URL http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet/reference/initialization .

Comment: "march" is the Maple archive utility, so (unless you want to do some archive work) do not execute *.mla.  Instead open it from within Maple.

Answer (score 2):

I hope, this might work.

```
DGALib := "E:/Maple work/General Maple Workout/DGApplications.mla/";

libname := DGALib, libname:
```

Answer (score 1):

In which directory have you put DGApplications.mla, aside from your Downloads folder?

Since you say you keep your Maple stuff on that directory on E:, I'm going to assume you put it there. Then at the top of the worksheet in which you wish to make use of the DGApplications library, add the line:

```
libname := libname, "E:\\Maple work\\General Maple Workout\\DGApplications.mla":
```

(Note that the directory delimiters have to be given with double backslashes because the backslash is an escape character.)

After that the definitions in DGApplications.mla should be available to you.

Comment: I have three drives in my Laptop C, E and F, I store all my Maple files in E, I have kept .mla file of this package along path E:\\Maple work\\General Maple Workout\\MLA_Files\\DGApplications.mla. When I add line suggested by you, it returns like this: libname := "C:\Program Files\Maple 18\lib", ".", "E:\Maple work\General Maple Workout\MLA_Files\DGApplications.mla" and the command DGEnvironment[Coordinate]([t, x, u], M) of this package not working means package is not loded.

Comment: There is not a single video on youtube related to installing Maple package...!!! Do you know one?

Comment: Sorry for the lateness of this reply. I don't know of such a video. Check to see if DGEnvironment is defined in your MLA library. You can see what is defined inside your MLA library with:

`LibraryTools:-ShowContents( "E:\\Maple work\\General Maple Workout\\MLA_Files\\DGApplications.mla");`